# How I can disable transition animation for edge swipe in UINavigationController?

Tags: swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller

How do I remove animation for `UINavigationController`? I have not found property in `UINavigationController` for this. Is a custom class only one way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the story board

[image]

In code you can do this:

```swift
@IBAction private func nextTapped() {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let otherViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OtherViewController") as? OtherViewController,
        let navigationController = navigationController  else {
        return
    }

    // when you push the view controller, pass in animated as false
    navigationController.pushViewController(otherViewController, animated: false)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next",
                                                        style: .plain,
                                                        target: self,
                                                        action: #selector(nextTapped))        
}
```